# Using multiple dispatch calls in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I am using multiple dispatch calls inside useEffect(). Each dispatch call has an async action inside and each async action is making an API call.

Now, the useEffect where all the dispatch calls are happening is obviously inside a **component** file.

The async actions are in separate **.action.tsx** files

And the API calls are in service files which are imported in **.action.tsx** files.

Eg:- if we have CardDetails.tsx as our component where we are calling two dispatch **GetCardNumber** and **GetValidity**, then we have two actions file **GetCardNumber.action.tsx** & **GetValidity.action.tsx**.

Also, we have two service files **GetCardNumber.service.tsx** &  **GetValidity.service.tsx** where we have the APIs.

The useEffect call looks like this -

```
useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(GetCardNumber(userId, setLoader));
},[])
```

The action file -

```
function GetCardDetails(id,setLoader) {
  return (dispatch) => {
   setLoader(true)
   //call to service file to make an API call
   setLoader(false)
   }
}
```

Now, the issue is that we are passing a loader state as a parameter while doing a dispatch call inside useEffect. The loader is set to true inside each action file before we make a call and is set to false after getting a response.

We came to know that the approach we are following is incorrect because one of the APIs is taking too long to provide response and because of that other APIs are setting the loader state to false and displaying the page.

So, in short, the page is getting loaded even when one of the APIs is in pending state, which is creating a bug.

Is there anyway we can resolve the issue? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the `useEffect` function you are making the dispatch calls from.

Comment: @kkmonlee done the changes